# Changing the border color in polygon

Tags: java, javafx, polygon

Using `Polygon` class, I have created a triangle.

By using `setStroke(Color.AQUA)`, I have changed the border color of that polygon. Triangle has 3 borders. How to set different color for every border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predefined method in `Polygon` for giving each border an individual color. You have to implement your own class or use a combination of 3 independent lines to make triangle.